# Index tab onTabClose event

Tags: jsf-2, primefaces

How can I get the index of the tab that received onTabClose event ?

```
<p:tabView rendered="#{testBean.renderTab}" id="WorkSpace" onTabClose="var title = #{tab.title} ; console.log(title); // Not working return null ">
        <c:forEach items="#{testBean.tabs}" var="tab" varStatus="status">
        <p:tab title="#{tab.title}" closable="true" id="tab${status.count}" >
        <ui:include src="#{tab.composition}" />
        </p:tab>
        </c:forEach>
    </p:tabView>
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The primefaces 5.1 documentation says the following:

> Tabview has three callbacks for client side. onTabChange is executed when an inactive tab is clicked, onTabShow is executed when an inactive tab becomes active to be shown and onTabClose when a closable tab is closed. All these callbacks receive index parameter as the index of tab.

So to get the index of the closed tag on client side you can use the following:

```
<p:tabView ... onTabClose="console.log(index);">
    ...
</p:tabView>
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your clear answer. When I use "function(index) { console.log(index); }" it throws an error . just console.log(index) is working fine. Can you update your answer to mark it resolved ?